# Resolving network tunneling socket could not be established error

Tags: node.js, npm

While trying to install node-inspector, I am getting the error:

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-21-generic
npm ERR! argv "/home/hira/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.7/bin/node" "/home/hira/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.7/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "node-inspector"
npm ERR! node v4.4.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.8
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET

npm ERR! network tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5002
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
```

I basically had a project based on node's [thin](https://github.com/runk/node-thin) module, that ran an http/https mitm proxy on 127.0.0.1:5002

Reading some answers on this issue, I have tried to remove the proxy settings by using:

```
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
```

as well as

```
npm config set proxy = null
```

so when I do npm config ls -l it shows both settings as null. However, still it refuses to install. I have even tried to remove my systems Network Proxy settings.

Could anyone help with this issue? I am running node `v4.4.7` and npm version `2.15.8` on Ubuntu 16.04 on Virtualbox. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps it's still available in an environment variable? `$HTTP_PROXY` or `$http_proxy` are quite common.

Comment: I tried checking my environment variables, and these appear in the list: `http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:5002/`
`https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:5002/`
`HTTPS_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:5002/`
`HTTP_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:5002/`
Could I set these all to null?

Comment: `unset http_proxy https_proxy HTTPS_PROXY HTTP_PROXY`

Comment: It works now, thanks a lot, I've had this issue in various other settings as well, where I could not unbind the proxy, so this might help me in checking whats wrong in those cases as well. Thanks.

Comment: @robertklep's solution works for me. I had a similar error but my context is that I tried to connect to outside from behind the wall.

So, I bypass proxy in VSCode by put this in Terminal > Integrated:Env Windows > settings.json

"terminal.integrated.env.windows": {

        "N0_PROXY": ".<domain>", }

--- Doing this still brings me this error so I `unset` the env variables

Answer (score 6):

As indicated by [robertklep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893780/robertklep) and [QPTR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/730314/qptr) in comments, removing the environment variables solved it for me

http_proxy

https_proxy

HTTPS_PROXY

HTTP_PROXY

Answer (score 0):

Below things worked for me, make sure environment variable HTTP_PROXY is unset before removing config entries. First line is very important.

```
set HTTP_PROXY=
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
npm config rm http-proxy
```